# Grab UNC Paths from txt file using regex

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to remove all data from a txt file that is not a unc path, so essentially, everything before the UNC path.

I have the txt file stored as a variable and want to do a find/replace.

My hopes for this regex string were to match the start of the file and replace the first set of double quotes and everything in between, this however is not working.

```
$lstdata -replace "^"""(\\.""),""



"\app\Program\" "\\Server1\H\RUN\client\client-CD\201901-CD\C116B726\Program\*.*"
"\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\Autorun\*.*"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\DXCOURFB.TTF"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\DXCOURFI.TTF"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\DXCOURFR.TTF"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\DXHELVFB.TTF"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\DXHELVFR.TTF"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\DXHELVPB.TTF"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\DXHELVPI.TTF"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\DXHELVPR.TTF"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\app.CFG"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\app.chm"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\dxr.cnt"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\app.TIP"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\app001.TTF"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\app002.TTF"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\dxr32.exe"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\app3201.EXE"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\DXTIMSPB.TTF"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\DXTIMSPI.TTF"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\DXTIMSPR.TTF"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\DX_View_EULA_v1.0.htm"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\FONTINFO.OFS"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\stamp.exe"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\tr01_d50.icm"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\watermark.enc"
"\app\Program\" "\\domain.com\prodmaster\jobs\company\PROGRAMS\app\2014.02\xerces-c_2_8.dll"
"\app\MNU\" "\\Server1\H\RUN\client\client-CD\201901-CD\C116B726\Mnu\*.*"
"\app\Data\20190101\PNCC116B726SAV\" "\\Server1\H\RUN\client\DATA\201901\C116B726\20190101\PNCC116B726SAV\*.*"
"\app\Data\20190104\MWCC116B726DDA\" "\\Server1\H\RUN\client\DATA\201901\C116B726\20190104\MWCC116B726DDA\*.*"
"\app\Data\20190125\MWCC116B726DDA\" "\\Server1\H\RUN\client\DATA\201901\C116B726\20190125\MWCC116B726DDA\*.*"
"\app\Data\20190131\MWCC116B726DDA\" "\\Server1\H\RUN\client\DATA\201901\C116B726\20190131\MWCC116B726DDA\*.*"
```

Comment: If your entire file looks like that, I suggest the following pattern: `(Get-Content -Path $file) -replace '.*?(?=\\\\.*?)"'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Construct a regular expression pattern that describes:

```
\\[HostName]\[ShareName]\[FilePath]
```

and then replace everything around it. This here should do it:

```
$lstdata -replace '.*(\\{2}[^\\"]+\\[^\\"]+\\[^"]+).*','$1'
#                  \/      \_____/  \_____/  \___/ \/
#              Stuff          |        |       |    Stuff
#                         HostName     |       |
#                                  ShareName   |
#                                           FilePath
```

Comment: Essentially you reversed how I was doing it?  Instead of trying to match and delete the first characters in the line to just leave the UNC path, you matched the UNC path and did what exactly?  What's the $1

Comment: `$1` means "first capture group" - notice the `()` around the UNC pattern. We're simply replacing `[anything][a unc path][anything]` with `[a unc path]`

Comment: is it somewhat safe to assume this lil bit here works for just abount any standard UNC path?  (\\{2}[^\\"]+\\[^\\"]+\\[^"]+)

Comment: Nice one +1, shouldn't the pseudo code start with 4 backslashes (or the other be single ones)?

Comment: I'm actually getting varied results with this string, some of the original unc paths are missing after the regex match

Comment: @LotPings `\\{2}` <-- 2 x backslash

Comment: @200mg do you have an example of a line where you don't get the expected results? It works against every example you've posted

Comment: I did refer to the pseudo code not the PowerShell code.

Comment: @LotPings you're right, that's super confusing, updated

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55010422/45375) with an **alternative based on the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split) operator**:

Looking at your input data, the UNC path on each line is in the 2nd (last) double-quoted (`"..."`) token, so you can split each line by `"` chars. and return the second-to-last token, i.e. the one with index `-2` (PSv4+ syntax, due to use of the **`.ForEach()` array method**):

```
# $lstdata is assumed to be an array with the file's lines.
# You can also call .ForEach on (Get-Content ...) directly.
$lstdata.ForEach({ $_ -split '"')[-2] })
```

If it's acceptable to include the enclosing double quotes in the result, you can simply split by *whitespace*, which is what the *unary* form of `-split` does:

```
$lstdata.ForEach({ (-split $_)[-1] })
```

In **PSv3-**, where the `.ForEach()` array method isn't available, you'll have to use the - **noticeably slower** - **`ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*** (whose built-in alias is `%`) in the *pipeline*:

```
# Without double quotes
$lstdata | ForEach-Object { ($_ -split '"')[-2] }

# With double quotes.
$lstdata | ForEach-Object { (-split $_)[-1] }
```

That said, the **upside of using the pipeline is the potential for *memory throttling***: if you were to provide the input in the same pipeline with `Get-Content` and output the results to a file in the same pipeline with, say, `Set-Content`, the input file wouldn't need to be loaded into memory *as a whole*, as reading and writing would occur one line at a time.